# Does -contains work for multidimensional arrays

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm struggling with the PowerShell -contains function for Arrays. I am wondering if it's possible to use -contains for multidimensional arrays.
What I've tried:

```
$pcMatrix = @(,@())
Import-Csv $outputFile |ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){
        if($pcMatrix -notmatch $property.Value.Split(";")[1]){
            $pcMatrix += ,($property.Value.Split(";")[1],$property.Value.Split(";")[2])
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $pcMatrix.Length
```

The write-host output is 1 and should be something around 800..

Thanks for your answers.

Yanick

Comment: The answer to your question is "no". However, I doubt that this is what you actually wanted to know, so please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: Thank you! I think I don't need more than a simple no. I am sure I'll find an other soloution. Tanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "Ansgar Wiechers" commented, the answer is no you can not use the -contains funktion with multidimensional arrays.